# Здравствуйте Можете ли вы проверить если я ответил правильно на задачу из книги по c++

Tags: c++, c++14

код:

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <string>
    using namespace std;


    int main() {
        string word;
    while(cin >> word) {
    if (word == "fuck" || word == "bitch") {
        word = "BLEp";
    }
    cout << word << endl;
    }



}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Приведите задачу в текстовом виде

Answer (score 1):

Вы не добавили, а заменили. Тоже маленькая ошибка: `BLEp` вместо `BLEEP`.

Мое предложение:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;


int main() {
    string disliked  = "Broccoli";
    string disliked2 = "fuck";
    string disliked3 = "bitch";
    string word;
    while(cin >> word) {
        if (word == disliked || word == disliked2  || word == disliked3) {
            word = "BLEEP";
        }
        cout << word << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: 1) Зачем `endl`? 2) Знаете ли Вы о существовании массивов? 3) А если ввести `BROCCOLI`?

Answer (score 0):

Набросал код который цензурит все слова введенные в массив `cens` не зависимо от регистра

```
#include<iostream>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string>
#include<vector>

std::string toupper(std::string &);

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    std::vector<std::string> cens{"fuck", "bitch", "broccoli"};
    std::string word;
    while (std::cin >> word) {
        for (int i = 0; i < cens.size(); ++i) {
            if (toupper(word) == toupper(cens[i])) {
                word = "BEEP";
                break;
            }
        }
        std::cout << word << ' ';
    }

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

std::string toupper(std::string & in)
{
    std::string out;
    for (int i = 0; i < in.size(); ++i) {
        if (in[i] >= 'a')
            out += in[i] - ('a' - 'A');
        else
            out += in[i];
    }
    return out;
}
```

Не нашел подходящей функции для перевода строки в верхний регистр, так что написал свою.

Comment: Хотя эффективность такого кода будет сильно падать при увеличении количества цензурируемых слов. Неплохо было бы перевести весь cens в верхний регистр с самого начала, благодоря этому не придется использовать каждый раз функцию toupper по отношению к этому массиву. Также вместо того, чтобы использовать toupper по отношению к word каждую итерацию цикла, лучше завести новую строку и в нее записать результат функции toupper(word) перед началом цикла и уже ее сравнивать с cens. Это, я думаю, вы и сами реализуете.

Answer (score -1):

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <set>
using namespace std;
class Fack {
  std::set<std::string> _da;

 public:
  void addWord(std::string s) {
    std::transform(s.begin(), s.end(), s.begin(), ::tolower);
    _da.insert(s);
  }
  bool find(std::string s) {
    std::transform(s.begin(), s.end(), s.begin(), ::tolower);
    if (_da.find(s) == _da.end()) {
      return false;
    }
    return true;
  }
};

int main() {
  Fack table;
  table.addWord("fuck");
  table.addWord("bitch");
  std::string word;
  while (cin >> word) {
    if (table.find(word)) {
      word = "BLEEP";
    }
    cout << word << endl;
  }
  return 0;
}
```